# ignore foreign key values on creating foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a foreign key constraints on tow tables classifications and fruits. These two tables already have data but the data in it does not flow with the constraints to be established:

Example

```
classification
id | name |
1  | Drupes
2  | Hesperidia 
3  | Berries

Fruits
id | name    | classification_fk
1  | Plums      1
2  | Olives  |  1
3  | Pears   |  4
4  | Lemon   |  2
5  | Grapes  |  2
6  | Tomatoes | 3
7  | Carrots  | 4
```

Now from the above, I am unable to establish a foreign key constraints due to the above data I inheritted in the db between the two tables. My challenge now is to establish a relationship with a query command where by missing constraints values will be ignored and the relationship set

Comment: Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql): "If you don't want to verify new `CHECK` or `FOREIGN KEY` constraints against existing data, use `WITH NOCHECK`. We don't recommend doing this, except in rare cases."

Comment: This is really a bad idea. Why do you want to allow data in your system that doesn't follow the constraints? You can kludge it into place using NOCHECK but you can't update those rows with circumventing your constraints again. Either adjust the constraints or fix the data.

Comment: I would do a select on distinct FKID then insert those values into the classification table with a name of 'TBD' or something along those lines so that you can properly update it later.